# Diff two tabs in Vim

Tags: vim, diff, tabs, vimdiff, buffer

Scenario: I have opened Vim and pasted some text. I open a second tab with `:tabe` and paste some other text in there.

Goal: I would like a third tab with a output equivalent to writing both texts to files and opening them with `vimdiff`.

The closest I can find is "diff the current buffer against a file", but not `diff`ing two open but unsaved buffers.

Comment: what's the tabe command?

Comment: @hhafez - open a new buffer in a new tab

Comment: It's short for :tabedit, aka :tabnew.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

I suggest opening the second file in the same tab instead of a new one.

Here's what I usually do:

```
:edit file1
:diffthis
:vnew
:edit file2
:diffthis
```

The [`:vnew`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:vnew) command splits the current view vertically so you can open the second file there. The [`:diffthis`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffthis) (or short: `:difft`) command is then applied to each view.

Comment: Fwiw, MacVim doesn't seem to have this by default, but I think you should be able to go to the terminal and type `vimdiff file1.txt file2.txt` and knock yourself out.

Comment: This is awesometastic. The `edit fileN` parts can be replaced with just pasting from the buffer, which lets you diff two chunks of text without pasting each into a tmp file (something that meld lets you do, but visual diff tools on the Mac are lacking in). It worked in MacVim for me out of the box.

Answer (score 38):

I would suggest trying [:diffthis](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffthis) or [:diffsplit](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffsplit)

Comment: `:vert diffsplit` makes for a more traditional diff-view than without `:vert`

Comment: You can :set diffopt+=vertical to make :vert the default.

Comment: Also, to scroll two windows simultaneously: `:set scrollbind` in both.

Comment: Does not work if I have to tabs, like asked in the question. If I do `:diffsplit` I get two connected buffers.

Answer (score 27):

When you have two files opened in vertical splitt, run

`:windo diffthis`

Comment: use ```:diffoff``` to turn off diff mode

Comment: But how do I change from two tabs to a vertical split?

Answer (score 4):

The content of all tabs are inside the buffers.
Look at the buffers:

```
:buffers
```

Find the right number for the content which should be diffed with your current tab content.

Open the buffer inside your current tab (f.e. buffer number 4)

```
:sb 4
```

Or do for vertical view:

```
:vertical sb 4
```

Then you can simple diff the content with

```
:windo diffthis
```

If you finished diff analysis you can input:

```
:windo diffoff
```